# How to tell which directory is the problem when tortoise svn complains

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am working under windows using the tortoise client and have made lots of changes, including many deletes, adds etc. When i try and commit i get the following error, but i cant tell which directory is the source of the problem?

*Cannot non-recursively commit a directory deletion of a directory with child nodes
To commit recursively and work around this error,
make sure that all child items of a checked folder
are also checked in the commit dialog.
Otherwise, TortoiseSVN must do a non-recursive commit
which does not allow directory deletion.*

Any tips, ive looked at the action log and so on but that only gives the same error message without the actual directory name .

Comment: FWIW, I think this can happen if you move/rename a folder, and then move/rename it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try using the command-line `svn` client, which might give more information.

In general, it's a good practice to use TortoiseSVN whenever you want to delete a folder in your working copy.

Comment: In the end i just used a different client RapidSVN did the job and skipped the complaint.

I voted this as the correct answer as the right thing to do was use anything but tortoise.

Answer (score 15):

You probably have a sparse checkout. To change this:

RightClick -> Tortoise -> Update To Revision...

Set Update Depth to Fully Recursive, and then hit OK

Comment: What seemed to work for me is to do then, and then do a regular update again.  (Or some such magic....).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and think it might be because I had an "ignore-on-commit" change list, with unchanged items (and unchecked of course).

To solve it,  I emptied the change list, closed the commit dialog and tried commit again: this time it worked just fine (I tried without closing the dialog first, and it failed).

I got the idea after reading tsvn help file, section "E.2.4. Commit". It says "If you have left all the file selection checkboxes in their default state, TortoiseSVN uses a single recursive commit of the working copy. If you deselect some files[...]every path must be specified individually on the commit command line"

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem today when tried to delete a folder with files. Removing change lists resolved the issue.

Comment: In my case, I had one Obstructed folder that I wasn't committing and that wasn't related to any of my changes that was causing the problem. Once I fixed that error, the commit worked.

Answer (score 5):

Commit the deleted items first.

Comment: This then means you end up lots of small commits, which really should go together as one big bunch.

Answer (score 3):

I could solve this error message from TortoiseSVN by committing at the root folder level of the repository - right click on the root folder of the repository and click commit. Clicking commit in the root folder is apparantly not the same and produces the error.